# How to grab children from parent in E-Commerce application

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm actually trying to create an E-Commerce application in Laravel and have the following database layout...

TABLE PRODUCTS:
product_id PK,
material,
description,
brand_id,
category_id,

TABLE PRODUCTS_CHILDREN:
id,
sku,
color,
price,
size,
qty,
product_id (FK to products table)

Now I'm a beginner in Laravel, but I was thinking to build an E-Commerce application and just wanted solve this issue before going to far.

My question is, is there a way, when displaying the products, to also retrieve the products children?

My thought process was:

Products -> get( product_id, $product_id ) -> getChildren ( product_id, product_id );

I know the syntax is not correct, I was just wondering if this was a possible solution in Laravel - by chaining the query ( as I believe is common with the Laravel framework ).

I guess what I'm asking is, what would the blade syntax look when displaying the data?

Judging from what I've seen from tutorials, it seems this would work, but I just wanted to confirm. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it would work once you set up relationships by following the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

For instance, in your example you would have two models, one for the products table and another for the products_children table (I would call them: **Product** and **Variant** respectively).

Between them you would have a *1:N* relation (one product can have many variants, one variants belongs to one and only one product).

So you could model the relation as following:
**Model: Product**

```php
class Product
{
    // Other methods/properties...

    public function variants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
    }
}
```

**Model: Variant**

```php
class Variant
{
    // This is needed, otherwise Laravel would search for a
    // table called as the pluralized model name's (eg: variants)
    protected $table = 'products_children';

    // Other methods/properties...

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'products_children');
    }
}
```

Once you set up relations like so you can chain methods like your example:

```php
// Assuming $id is the variable holding the product id you want to retrive
$product = Product::find($id);
$variants = $product->variants;

// You can now access the main Product properties, but you can also
// iterate through each Variant entity linked to that product.
```

Depending on the query use case, the last query might not be the optimal way to do it. You sometimes have to eager-load the relation for all of entities you are querying. If you want to look more in depth about this topic, refer to the official documentation.

**Disclaimer:** The code I wrote it's just a PoC and hasn't been tested. It was written to give a quick overview about how simple is to setup and use relationships among models.